# Spring boot + Embedded tomcat missing session variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, tomcat

guys !
I'm using spring boot 1.4.1 with embedded tomcat. The problem is that when user is successfully logged i append session variable with the username. After some time this session variable is empty, but the user is still authenticated. What could the problem ? How can investigate this issue?

Best regards.

Comment: probably there is a session timeout, check property server.session.timeout

Comment: This is true ... but why the user is still logged in ?
www.domain.com/home  - requires user to be authenticated. So the user still can visit /home page, but in this home page username session variable is not available. The user can hit this page 20 minutes after session variable is not available and still not to redirect user to login page. 

So, session must not be expired ?